# Passing a huge String as post parameter to a servlet

Tags: java, servlets

I have a servlet which receives a huge string (apprx 301695 length) as a post parameter.

Every minute, a .net application sends such huge string to the servlet.

Initially I used to get the string as below:

```
 Line 1: String str = request.getParameter("data");
```

But, after 3-4 hours. I get the following exception:

```
 java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

Then I commented Line: 1.  Even though, My servlet code does not receive the string, I get the same exception as mentioned above.

Please guide me. How should I deal with this issue?  I have read many blogs and articles related to it, increased the heap size and other things. But, haven't found any solution.

Original code was like below:

```
private String scanType = "";
private static final String path = "D:\\Mobile_scan_alerts";
private static final String stockFileName = "stock.txt";
private static final String foFileName = "fo.txt";
private static Logger logger = null;
private String currDate = "";
private DateFormat dateFormat;
private StringBuffer stockData;
private StringBuffer foData;
 StringBuffer data = new StringBuffer("");
// For average time of received data
private static float sum = 0;
private static float count = 0;
private static float s_sum = 0;
private static float s_count = 0;
private static float fo_sum = 0;
private static float fo_count = 0;

private static final File dir = new File(path);
private static final File stockFile = new File(path + "\\" + stockFileName);
private static final File foFile = new File(path + "\\" + foFileName);

public void init() {

    logger = MyLogger.getScanAlertLogger();

    if(logger == null) {
        MyLogger.createLog();
        logger = MyLogger.getScanAlertLogger();
    }

}

/**
 * Processes requests for both HTTP <code>GET</code> and <code>POST</code>
 * methods.
 *
 * @param request servlet request
 * @param response servlet response
 * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
 * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
 */
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    response.setContentType("text/plain");
    String strScan = "";

    try {

        String asof = null;

        scanType = request.getParameter("type");
        scanType = scanType == null ? "" : scanType;


        if(scanType.length() > 0){

            if(scanType.equalsIgnoreCase("s")) {
                stockData = null;
                stockData = new StringBuffer(request.getParameter("scanData"));
                stockData = stockData == null ? new StringBuffer("") : stockData;
            } else {
                foData = null;
                foData = new StringBuffer(request.getParameter("scanData"));
                foData = foData == null ? new StringBuffer("") : foData;
            }

        }

        asof = request.getParameter("asof");
        asof = asof == null ? "" : asof.trim();

        // Date format without seconds
        DateFormat formatWithoutSec = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm");

        dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
        Date tmp = new Date();

        // format: yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss
        currDate = dateFormat.format(tmp);

        //format: yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm
        Date asofDate = formatWithoutSec.parse(asof);
        Date cDate = formatWithoutSec.parse(currDate);
        cDate.setSeconds(0);


        System.out.println(asofDate.toString()+" || "+cDate.toString());

        int isDataExpired = asofDate.toString().compareTo(cDate.toString());

        if(isDataExpired > 0 || isDataExpired == 0) {

            if(scanType != null && scanType.length() > 0) {
                checkAndCreateDir();
                strScan = scanType.equalsIgnoreCase("s") ? "Stock Data Recieved at "+currDate
                        : "FO Data Recieved at "+currDate;
                //System.out.println(strScan);
            } else {
                strScan = "JSON of scan data not received properly at "+currDate;
                //System.out.println("GSAS: received null or empty");
            }

        } else {
            strScan = "GSAS: " + scanType + ": Received Expired Data of "+asofDate.toString()+" at "+cDate.toString();
            System.out.println(strScan);
        }
        scanType = null;


    } catch (Exception ex) {
        strScan = "Mobile server issue for receiving scan data";
        System.out.println("GSAS: Exception-1: "+ex);
        logger.error("GetScanAlertServlet: processRequest(): Exception: "+ex.toString());
    } finally {
        logger.info("GetScanAlertServlet: "+strScan);
        out.println(strScan);
    }

}

private void checkAndCreateDir() {

    try {
            boolean isStock = false;
            Date ddate = new Date();
            currDate = dateFormat.format(ddate);
            sum += ddate.getSeconds();
            count++;
            logger.info("Total Average Time: "+(sum/count));

            if(scanType.equalsIgnoreCase("s")){ //For Stock
                setStockData(stockData);

                Date date1 = new Date();
                currDate = dateFormat.format(date1);
                s_sum += date1.getSeconds();
                s_count++;
                logger.info("Stock Average Time: "+(s_sum/s_count));

                //file = new File(path + "\\" + stockFileName);
                isStock = true;

            } else if (scanType.equalsIgnoreCase("fo")) { //For FO
                setFOData(foData);

                Date date2 = new Date();
                currDate = dateFormat.format(date2);
                fo_sum += date2.getSeconds();
                fo_count++;
                logger.info("FO Average Time: "+(fo_sum/fo_count));

                //file = new File(path + "\\" +foFileName);
                isStock = false;
            }


            if(!dir.exists()) { // Directory not exists
                if(dir.mkdir()) {

                    if(isStock)
                        checkAndCreateFile(stockFile);
                    else
                        checkAndCreateFile(foFile);

                }
            } else { // Directory already exists

                    if(isStock)
                        checkAndCreateFile(stockFile);
                    else
                        checkAndCreateFile(foFile);
            }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("GSAS: Exception-2: "+e);
        logger.error("GetScanAlertServlet: checkAndCreateDir(): Exception: "+e);
    }

}

private void checkAndCreateFile(File file) {

    try{
        if(!file.exists()){ // File not exists

            if(file.createNewFile()){
                writeToFile(file);
            }

        } else { // File already exists
            writeToFile(file);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("GSAS: Exception-3: "+e);
        logger.error("GetScanAlertServlet: checkAndCreateFile(): Exception: "+e.toString());
    }
}


private void writeToFile(File file) {

    FileOutputStream fop = null;

    try{

        if(scanType.equalsIgnoreCase("s")){ //For Stock
            data = getStockData();
        } else if (scanType.equalsIgnoreCase("fo")) { //For FO
            data = getFOData();
        }

        if(data != null && data.length() > 0 && file != null){

            fop = new FileOutputStream(file);

            byte[] contentBytes = data.toString().getBytes();
            for(byte b : contentBytes){
                fop.write(b);
            }
            //fop.write(contentBytes);

            fop.flush();


        } else {

            System.out.println("GSAS: Data is null/empty string");
            logger.info("GSAS: Data is null or empty string");

        }
        data = null;
    } catch (Exception  e) {
        System.out.println("GSAS: Exception-4: "+e);
        logger.info("GetScanAlertServlet: writeToFile(): Exception: "+e.toString());

    } finally {

        try {

            if(fop != null)
                fop.close();

        } catch (IOException ex) {
                java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(GetScanAlertServlet.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}

private String readFromFile(String fileName){

    String fileContent = "";
    try{

        String temp = "";
        File file = new File(fileName);
        if(file.exists()){

            FileReader fr = new FileReader(file);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);

            while((temp = br.readLine()) != null)
            {
                fileContent += temp;
            }
            br.close();
        } else {
            System.out.println("GSAS: File not exists to read");
            logger.info("GetScanAlertServlet: File not exists to read");
        }

        temp = null;
        file = null;

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("GSAS: Exception-5: "+e);
        logger.error("GetScanAlertServlet: readFromFile(): Exception: "+e.toString());
    }
    return fileContent;
}

public StringBuffer getStockData() {

    //String temp="";
    //StringBuffer temp = (StringBuffer)scanDataSession.getAttribute("stock");
    //if(temp != null && temp.length() > 0) {
    //    return temp;
    //}
    if(stockData != null && stockData.length() > 0){
        return stockData;
    } else {
        stockData = null;
        stockData = new StringBuffer(readFromFile(path + "\\"+ stockFileName));
        return stockData;
    }
}


public StringBuffer getFOData(){

    //String temp="";
    //StringBuffer temp = (StringBuffer)scanDataSession.getAttribute("fo");
    //if(temp != null && temp.length() > 0) {
    //    return temp;
    //}
    if(foData != null && foData.length() > 0) {
        return foData; 
    } else {
        foData = null;
        foData = new StringBuffer(readFromFile(path + "\\" + foFileName));
        return foData;
    }   
}

}
```

Comment: Maybe if you copy the stacktrace and the relevant servlet code, somebody can help you. If you commented that line., it seems that your problem got nothing to do with reading the huge string,

Comment: I am using visual vm to track heap size.  The surprising thing is that, even though i have commented that line. it still shows the same error after some time.  However, posting the older code:

Comment: I think your Servlet is not thread safe.  Or it implements SingleThreadModel?

Answer (score 0):

Increasing heap size is not a good solution for this problem. Your upstream application should stop sending huge strings to your Servlet.

Your upstream(.net) application should consider writing all the data to a file, just need to send the location of the file as a parameter to your Servlet. Once your servlet receives notification from the upstream, you consider downloading/reading file from the location.

> Then I commented Line: 1. Even though, My servlet code does not
>   receive the string (as commented), I get the same exception as
>   mentioned above.

The Line: 1 is to read data. If you comment it, you wont receive the String.

Comment: As it is time critical, we cannot afford to download the file.  Actually, the String we receive is JSON String and we have to scan the json object to fetch data from it.

Comment: What is your current Xms and Xmx?

Comment: 128m and 1024m respectively

Comment: I seriously doubt, whether old strings were garbage colleted or not?  Is your String causing heap to go beyond 1GB??

Comment: No. Older Strings were not garbage collected somehow as longer strings garbage collection is different than shorter Strings. Even if my servlet has 0 line of code & if .NET app keeps sending huge String as mentioned in my post, heap size becomes full.   It is also strange to me. But it happens.  Seriously need to go deep into it.   Thinking of using Protobuff, GZip to Compress string or MessagePack.

Comment: I think heap is getting allocated once ur servlet receives the request irrespective of whether u read the string or not. From ur comments, there is should be some active reference to the huge old strings because of which those are not GCed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use apache commons-fileupload library Streaming API, this way, you get your uploaded file as a stream and write it to the file :

```
ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload();

// Parse the request
FileItemIterator iter = upload.getItemIterator(request);
while (iter.hasNext()) {
    FileItemStream item = iter.next();
    String name = item.getFieldName();
    InputStream stream = item.openStream();
    if (item.isFormField()) {
        System.out.println("Form field " + name + " with value "
            + Streams.asString(stream) + " detected.");
    } else {
        System.out.println("File field " + name + " with file name "
            + item.getName() + " detected.");
        // Process the input stream
        ...
    }
}
```

Now You have InputStream, so you can write it in the output stream.

But to use this you need your .NET application to upload the bytes to the server instead of sending entire String as request param.

http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-fileupload/streaming.html

Answer (score 0):

Please check your VM Arguments and modify them approriately if you have no control of the String being passed to the servlet. For examples:

```
set JAVA_OPTS=-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Xms128m -Xmx1024m -XX:PermSize=64m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m
```

Check for a complete explanation [here](http://www.mkyong.com/tomcat/tomcat-javalangoutofmemoryerror-permgen-space/).

Answer (score 0):

We used GZip compression/decompression to lower the size of the string.  And it worked effectively.

So, the .net service compressed the huge string, sent it to our Servlet. We then decompress it at our server.