# How can I receive a large string in Java Servlet?

Tags: java, jquery, jsp, servlets, url-parameters

I am building a JSP application. I am trying to send an screenshot image from the page to the servlet by using base64 encoding. It makes the returning string super long with 100k characters length. So when I post this to the servlet and with getParameter, I am getting null there.

Is there a way to get them by chunks are am I missing something?

Comment: The default for Tomcat of `maxPostSize` is 2M

Comment: Where do I change that? server.xml file in Eclipse has only few lines, which don't have maxPostSize in it? do I have to manually enter it?

Comment: I tried changing it, I still can't read that parameter in the servlet, for transferring base64 what kind of contentType do I set? let me show you the first few lines of that string. `data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAr0AAAKWCAYAAABETyEtAAAgAElEQVR4XuzdV5Bc14E.............`

Comment: Are you sure it is working with a smaller String?

Comment: I found some information may helps. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36734311/passing-a-huge-string-as-post-parameter-to-a-servlet

Answer (score 1):

I found this maybe useful for you.

[Passing a huge String as post parameter to a servlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36734311/passing-a-huge-string-as-post-parameter-to-a-servlet)

Namit Rana:

We used GZip compression/decompression to lower the size of the string. And it worked effectively.

So, the .net service compressed the huge string, sent it to our Servlet. We then decompress it at our server.

Comment: Thanks, I will take a look on that! BTW if anyone can tell me is there a way where we can stream our parameter values as we do for files?